# Stop page from scrolling when div is scrolled to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Basically, I have a scrolling div. I want the div to scroll obviously, but once scrolled all the way to the bottom, if the user continues to scroll, I don't want the page itself to scroll. Basically, when the mouse is in the div, I want the scrolling to be only within the div, and then when the mouse is outside of the div i want the page to scroll. Is there any way of doing this? I'm using jquery for other aspects of the site as well so I have that if it helps.

Comment: Code samples? **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only thing i could see happening is that the focus is not set to the div when you move into it, and then loose focus when you move out.

Example JavaScript:

```
<div onMouseOver="JavaScript:this.focus();" onMouseOut="JavaScript:this.blur();">
```

Also, be sure that your CSS Class for your Div has the following, in this specific order:

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
```